# Preview PDF from a source PDF file PHP

Tags: php, pdf

A bit of advice if possible is required here.

I have a need to allow a user to upload a large 60 page + PDF and from that create a 16 Page preview PDF. So thats a PDF from the uploaded PDF.

I want to build this in PHP and after a while googling I am struggling to find a solution. I am able to to create images without a problem and one solution I have looked into is creating a PDF from the set of images but surely there is a better way?

Anyway some guidance would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I googled for 'php pdf reader library' and found these links:

http://www.pdfparser.org

http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html

and so on. Isn't there any library that suites your needs? The first one looks very good.